# Python time analysis

Tags: python-3.x

General python function question.

### CASE 1 TIME: ~80s

```
from helper import square
val = 200000000
lis=[]
for i in range(0,val):
    square(lis,i)
```

### CASE 2 TIME: ~50s

```
from helper import square
val = 200000000
lis=[]
for i in range(0,val):
    lis.append(i*i)
```

This is a very trivial example related to a problem I'm trying to tackle in my program, but if I understand correctly functions in python are passed by reference rather than a full copy, maybe I underestimate how much extra work it takes to pass something by "reference" but why does a function call take more time than doing the same job inside the function without another call?

Comment: try `lis=[i*i for i in range(val)]`: Your problem isn't the question of passing by reference or value, you're having way more happening, mostly language parsing, name lookup, function-to-name-mapping, figuring out what to call when you say `thingfrommodule operator()` etc. This isn't exactly assembly!

Comment: What is your definition of `square?`

Comment: lis.append(i*i) literally the same thing.